# Is the NATO/ICAO or ITU figure pronunciation more common?

Tags: procedure, phone, phonetic-alphabet

I know the NATO/ICAO pronunciation of modifying 3, 4, 5, and 9 to "tree", "fower", "fife", and "niner", respectively, but I just discovered [the ITU figure pronunciations are vastly different](https://life.itu.int/radioclub/rr/ap14.pdf).

Which are more common, and which should I learn as a prospective ham?

Comment: I haven't heard the ITU figure pronunciations used in amateur radio in the US or Canada. I'd suggest learning the NATO/ICAO if you're getting started in that region.

Answer (score 2):

> 3, 4, 5, and 9 to "tree", "fower", "fife", and "niner", respectively,

Those pronunciations are not used on Amateur Radio.

Answer (score -2):

My suggestion is to learn the NATO/ICAO pronunciation. That's what is used by nearly every airline pilot and military group.

Comment: The OP is asking about amateur radio, not aircraft or military.